# Can there be two winners at the same time in Catan?

Tags: catan

Imagine the following setup:

- Player A has 6 points, including the Longest Road.
- Player B has 8 points with an equally long road.
- Player C has 9 points with a shorter road.

Now what would happen if Player C places a village, breaking Player A's road chain? At that moment Player A would have 4 points, while both Player B and Player C would have 10.

In this case, who would be declared the victor?

Comment: I removed your second question, since we prefer that each question only asks one question. It is an interesting question however so I would recommend you repost it as its own question.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Only the player who is currently taking their turn can win the game, so player C would be the winner.

Official Rule:

> ENDING THE GAME
>   If you have—or reach—10 victory
>   points on your turn, the game ends
>   immediately and you win! You can only
>   win during your turn. If somehow you
>   find you have 10 victory points during
>   another player’s turn, you must wait
>   until your next turn to claim victory.

Source: [Downloads page on www.catan.com](http://www.catan.com/game/catan#downloads)

Comment: IIRC the 5-6 player expansion allows multiple players to win; since it changes the rules so you can build on any turn.

Comment: @esoterik There is nothing in the [5-6 player extension rules](http://www.catan.com/faq-page/94) that changes the winning conditions. If you build a settlement that secures enough points for victory during someone else's turn, you still have to wait for your turn to claim victory.

Comment: Notably, in extreme cases you can get 11 points and still lose, if the active player builds a settlement that interrupts a different player's longest road.

Answer (score 1):

No, there can't be two winners at the same time even if they have the same point total. You can win only on your turn.

Player C wins, because he reaches ten points (after adding the village) **on his turn.**

If Player C started with eight points, and added a village for nine, then play would continue to Player A. That's true even though Player B has ten points, because Player A might break up Player B's longest road (or do something else to reduce his point total). If the play then gets around to Player B and he still has ten points, he wins without playing, because someone else "made" his ten points for him. But he can't win until his turn.