# Who would win in this case?

Tags: catan

Case scenario:

- Player 1: (9 points total)

  - 3 cities (6 points)
  - 3 hidden points
- Player 2: (9 points total)

  - 3 cities (6 points)
  - 1 village (1 point)
  - longest road
- Player 3: (9 points total)

  - 4 cities (8 points)
  - 1 village (1 point)

It's turn of player3, he puts 2 roads and a village, which 'cuts' the longest road of player2, which gives the longest road award to player1 (+2 points for him out of his turn)

In his turn, player3 reaches 10 points. But player1 has 11 points (3 of them are hidden points)

Who wins?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can there be two winners at the same time in Catan?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/25804/can-there-be-two-winners-at-the-same-time-in-catan)

Comment: For a once popular unnamed clone of the game with an online ranking system, the point spread was taken into account when determining how many rating points a player gains or loses.  I feel like I remember seeing someone gaming the system by continuing to play beyond the required number of points to the point where when someone else had managed to reach the required number of points the spread was so extreme that the winner had lost rating despite having been the person to claim victory.